# Matching newlines in regular expression with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have some data that looks like this:

```
:setvar DatabaseName "CI_1814903104"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "CI_1814903104"
--etc.    

GO
```

I wish to replace all sql cmd variable lines (lines that start with :setvar) with an empty string such that the data looks like this:

```
--etc.    

GO
```

This statement (where `$script` contains the data) seems to do the trick but still leaves the newlines:

```
$script -replace ":setvar(.*$)", ""
```

results in:

```
 
 
--etc.    

GO
```

How do I include the newline in the match? It seems to match it but not actually be replaced. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This assumes that your data is being read in from some file.  Depending on how you are reading in your data, you may have a collection of strings instead of a single string.

```
PS C:\> $script = Get-Content data.txt

# Get-Content returns each line as a string object in an Object[].
PS C:\> $script.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> $script[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Piping Get-Content to Out-String as demonstrated below will ensure that you get a single string, and then you can operate on the windows newline character to remove the appropriate lines.

```
PS <C:\> $script = ( Get-Content data.txt | Out-String ).Trim()
PS <C:\> $script -replace ":setvar(.*)`n", ""
--etc.

GO
```

Comment: Thanks for reading between the lines - it was the gc as an array that was screwing me up. P.S. Change the ``r``n to \r\n and you get the points!

Comment: @Plymouth223 The escape character in Powershell is the backtick. For this case of working with regex, either works -- but that is not typically the case.  Try it. :)

Comment: Ah, got it - my issue was I tried yours and it didn't work so I changed the expression to ":setvar(.*)\n" and it did. The file only contained \n for the newlines. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha.  That's my bad for assuming windows carriage returns.  Even funnier is that expression should catch `\r` anyway, so there's not much point in keeping it around -- I'll edit the post for that.

Comment: Maybe `Get-Content -Raw` would also do the job without piping to `Out-String` See
[Microsoft Docs - Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1#example-6--get-raw-content)